# XFCE Terminal: Last line goes out of screen after opening a new tab

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, xfce4-terminal

I switched from Ubuntu to Xubuntu recently.

I expirienced a problem which drives me crazy:

When I open a Terminal i usually move them to one half of the screen (with the Windows and an Arrow button).
When I do so and open a new tab in the terminal window for the first time (and the additional area for the tabs appears in the top area of the window) the last line of the terminal goes out of the screen. Pressing the key combination to move the window to one side of the screen again resizes the window to bring back the last line into the visual screen.

I am looking for a better way to solve this problem than pressing this key combination twice per terminal.

Comment: I can reproduce this behavior in my xfce4-terminal. Opening the first tab shouldn't resize the window at all, this is  a strange design. I found [this old bug](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=10551) which is marked as fixed though, probably the bug is somehow reintroduced.

Comment: The bug report mook765 linked in the comment is exactly what my problem is about.
I decided to comment on that bug to make aware of this problem.

Comment: You can always install and use a different terminal emulator like `konsole` or `gnome-terminal`. I just installed and tried `konsole` which behaves much nicer.

Comment: I used `terminator` which does not run into this problem. Its sad since the xfce4-terminal has some nice features (like a well integrated and super easy to use naming function for tabs) which where one of the reasons I switched to Xubuntu.